# change all the consonant for the letter p

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace all the consonants of a sentence with the letter p.

I have tried this code below but sadly this isn't working, I'm not used to this function(`str.replace()`) and I am beginning the python course.

```python
x=str(input())
y=x.split()
cons="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
if cons in y:
    x.replace(cons,"p")
    print(y)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, please be more descriptive than "isn't working". Does the code fail to even begin running? Does the code shut down your computer? Being descriptive when asking a question can save people a lot of time trying to help you and can also help people having a similar problem find this question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is loop over each letter in your `cons` variable and try to replace it. I should point out that the `str.replace()` method doesn’t work in-place so you’ll have to assign the result back to `x`:

```
...
for c in cons:
    x = x.replace(c, 'p')
```

You say that you are new to Python. In the code above, the `for` loop will loop over each letter in the string and on each ‘iteration’, the variable `c` is set to the next letter in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`if cons in y` tests whether the entire string in `cons` is one of the elements of `y`. But the elements of `y` are all just single characters, not long strings.

You need to loop over each character in `y`, and then test if that character is in `cons`.

```
for index, letter in enumerate(y):
    if letter in cons:
        y[index] = 'p'
x = "".join(y)
print(x)
```

Or you can loop over `cons` and replace each of those letters in `x`. You need to assign the result of `x.replace` back to `x`; strings in Python are immutable, so this returns a new string, it doesn't modify the original.

```
for letter in cons:
    x = x.replace(letter, "p")
print(x)
```

You can also do the entire thing in one step using a regular expression:

```
import re
x = re.replace(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]', 'p', x)
print(x)
```

BTW, you don't need to write `str(input())`. `input()` always returns a string in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

why print `y`in every loop, you don't even touch `y` once.

`y` is totally independend from `x`. When you do `y=x.split()`, a new list will be created and referenced by `y`. There will be no more linkage between `x` and `y`.

Furthermore `cons in y`will test if the whole `cons` string is included in `y`.

You can make it much easier, there is no need to create `y`. `replace`can directly operate on your string.

```
x = input()
cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
for con in cons:
    x = x.replace(con, "p")
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just find the occurrences of consonants in the string and replace them with p's. Loop through the list of consonants and run `replace`. If the consonant exists in the string it will replace it.

```
x = str(input())
cons="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
for elem in cons:
    x = x.replace(elem, p)
print(x)
```